# Is there any way to improve performance and execution time of this code? - PHP

Tags: php, refactoring, execution-time

First time asking this kind of question. I am working on a small internal app that works along an external API for provisioning purpose.

The code essentially is comprised of a series of forms where the user inputs data, this data is then sent to the API to register new customers.

This is somewhat quite a linear process I will try to explain:

1. Contact Creation: Basic customer info (email, adress...).
2. Customer Creation: More advanced info, for a customer to be created there must be a `contactId` belonging to this customer.
3. Subscriber Creation: Info linking customer to the service acquired. The previous step has to be completed and a `customerId` must exist.
4. Service Creation: Lasts bits of advanced info about the service. Once again, a `suscriberId` needs to exist in order to link the service.

I've managed a more or less quick process with a few tweaks here and there, but the first step (Contact) has a method I can't seem to improve, which in turn causes this process to take up to a full minute!

As the whole process described earlier, the creation of each one of these is very linear too.

The API documentation states that the resuts of any GET should be paginated to a max of 10 entries, but following this further increases the time over the minute. Manual experiments showed that the best ratio is about 500 entries per page or in some cases, even the whole number of entries proved to be the fastest way rather than going 10 by 10.

Since the contact email can't be duplicated, one of the first things to do is check for the email provided in the form and compare it to all the already existing emails stored.

In order to provide the `$page` and `$entries` to the API call, I must first fetch the total number of conctacts. This number appears when calling the API to get the contacts. So the first methos I use is:

```php
function fetchTotalContacts($uri, $auth){
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $uri.'?page=1&rows=1',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: $auth')
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    $totalContacts = $response['total_count'];

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($http_code != 200) {
        echo "Error en fetchTotalContacts() - Código: $http_code | ";
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);

    return $totalContacts;
}
```

Now having `$totalContacts` I can proceed and search if the email has been already registered, and this is the step I suspect to be responsible for the high execution time. This method searchs the contacts and their emails, if it finds no coincidence, proceeds to create the contact with the data provided.

```php
function checkDuplicatedEmail($uri, $totalContacts, $contactEmailArray, $auth, $contactEmail, $dataContact){
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $uri.'?page=1&rows='.$totalContacts,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: $auth')
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $customers = curl_exec($ch);
    $customers = json_decode($customers, true);

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
    if ($http_code != 200) {
        echo "Error en checkDuplicatedEmail() - Código: $http_code | ";
    }


    curl_close($ch);

    /*
    foreach ($customers['_embedded']['ngcp:customercontacts'] as $customer) {
    
        $email = $customer['email'];

        array_push($contactEmailArray, $email);
    }

    if (in_array($contactEmail, $contactEmailArray)) {
        echo('El email utilizado ya ha sido registrado en la base de datos');
        die();
    }else{
        $contactCreated = createContact($uri, $dataContact);
        return $contactCreated;
    }
    */

    $repeated = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < $totalContacts ; $i++) {
        if ($contactEmail == $customer["_embedded"]["ngcp:customercontacts"][$i]["email"]) {
            $repeated += 1;
        }
    }

    if ($repeated > 0) {
        die(echo('El email utilizado ya ha sido registrado en la base de datos'));
    }else{
        $contactCreated = createContact($uri, $dataContact, $auth);
        return $contactCreated;
    }
}
```

As you can see, these are the quickiest options I've found, both making the whole process take 40s, which is too much still.

The response for `createContact($uri, $dataContact, $auth);` is a success code (400, 201..), so when I want to go to the next step I do need to, again, search all the contacts to find the one I just created and get the id. Fortunately, here I can simply skip to the last 20 contacts (not the last one directly so it can be used simoultaneousy without issues) and search there, this makes it real quick, but for the email there is no such skip, all the entries must be analyzed.

I don't know how to drop the time here, the rest of the code consists of fetching the `contactId` and creating the customer so not much to do there as it is now.

If any of you deem necessary to see the rest of the page I wil update the post.

As a final reminder, I have manually tried with different configs of pages and entries and for this page, the fastest was `1 page - All entries`. I've also tried taking the for/each loop outside the method, to no avail. All advice is welcome,
Thanks for the help provided!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: Maybe I will @JohnConde, maybe I will... 
Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: [Cross-posted at Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248187/52915)